# Visual Studio Code launching Chrome (Edge is my default browser) when debugging Blazor app

Tags: visual-studio-code, blazor

Visual Studio Code 1.46.1 launching Chrome (Edge is my default browser) when debugging Blazor app. Is there a way to have Visual Studio Code launch Edge instead? I have Edge configured as default browser in Windows.

Comment: Do you have any debugger extension installed? like chrome debug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. There is a browser setting in the launch.json file in the blazor project. One can set the browser to chrome or edge. That worked for me.

Comment: For anyone who needs the exact json, the configuration is `"browser" : "edge"`.